# IMG src containing variable wont display

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure why this is failing...

```
<script> var $username = localStorage.getItem('user'); </script>
<img src="//MYCLOUDEX4/Library/Picture/poster-" + $username + ".jpg" alt="Poster">
```

The source folder contains "poster-Ralph.jpg" and $username contains "Ralph".

Comment: It looks like youre missing a basic understanding of html and js. They are strictly seperated ( but JS can *modify* HTML)

Comment: With JS, yes.  I only started learning it yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write javascript syntax directly in your html code.

Try adding the src inside your `<script>`.

This is an example using only javascript:

```
<img id="myimg" src="" alt="Poster">
<script> 
    var $username = localStorage.getItem('user'); 
    document.getElementById("myimg").src="//MYCLOUDEX4/Library/Picture/poster-" + $username + ".jpg";
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, as you probably guessed I am a newbie at JS. Because I will be dealing with mulitple calls, I have placed the $username var in a separate script at the top of the page so it's only called once.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not an expert either, just keep working hard and google a lot and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<img>` tag is out of script's scope, so you cannot use script variables in there.

You should modify image's source straight in script (e.g. with jQuerys. `.attr()` method).

Example

```
<script>
var $username = localStorage.getItem('user');
var src = "//MYCLOUDEX4/Library/Picture/poster-" + $username + ".jpg"
$('img').attr('src', src);
</script>

<img alt="Poster">
```

@Carl Kroeger Ihl answer is better if you don't want to use jQuery for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Bartosz, I may look at JQuery at a later stage when I am more familiar with JS.  I would probably look at using .append to simply add the user name before the .jpg suffix of existing "poster.jpg" files.  This way, I could reduce the size of my HTML page significantly.